# Maven eclipse integraton

Tags: eclipse, maven-3, maven-plugin

I'm trying to install **Maven Eclipse plugin M2E**, but it's update site is [here](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases) isn't working.
Others Maven plugins at **Eclipse Marketplace** are showing the **'Not found'** page too.

Comment: The UpdateSite seems to be down, that's why nothing is working. See http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/

Answer (score 1):

Since Eclipse 4.3.x the Maven integration can be installed directly from the default Eclipse update site that also ships all the other standard Eclipse plugins.

Comment: If you download the JEE variant M2E is included.